# How to include Dagger Debug SubModule for Debug build?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm create a Dagger AppComponent in my application as below

```
protected AppComponent createComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
}
```

The AppModule includes a `FeatureModule as below.

```
@Module(includes = {FeatureModule.class})
public class AppModule {
   // All the provides here
}
```

Now, I plan to have a separate item for Debug build in the FeatureModule. So I create my FeatureDebugModule inheriting from FeatureModule

```
@Module
public class FeatureDebugModule extends FeatureModule {

    @Override
    protected void debugBuildSpecificConfig() {
         // Something specific to debug
    }
}
```

With that I also create AppDebugModule inherit from AppModule

```
@Module(includes = {FeatureDebugModule.class})
public class AppDebugModule : AppModule {
}
```

And lastly, I made I made AppDebugApplication that setup the Dagger Component as below

```
protected AppComponent createComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppDebugModule(this)).build();
}
```

Somehow, the code doesn't access the `FeatureDebugModule` in my debug mode, but still on the `FeatureModule` code. What did I do wrong?

Comment: how did you define your "AppDebugApplication" ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently for Dagger, the loaded module is based on what defined in the Component's modules. Hence in Debug, I use as below.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppDebugModule.class})
public interface AppDebugComponent extends AppComponent {
    // Inject
}
```

And the dagger  component creation

```
DaggerAppDebugComponent.builder().appDebugModule(new AppDebugModule(this)).build();
```

In release, I used as below

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppReleaseModule.class})
public interface AppReleaseComponent extends AppComponent {
    // Inject
}
```

And the dagger  component creation

```
DaggerAppReleaseComponent.builder().appReleaseModule(new AppReleaseModule(this)).build();
```